# automatic name of variables vs2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Resharper has a very useful feature. When a user types the object name (name of class) it suggests the name of the variable. Can I get this same feature without resharper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not without an add-on like ReSharper.

Comment: What's a pity. It's sad information. I'm wondering, whether exist possibility to write own plugin for visual?

Comment: Yes you can write your own plugins, thats why there are plugins, like reSharper...